# Drupal Error message

Tags: 6

I received these two error messages today.  Not sure where they came from or what I did to cause it.  Any suggestions on how I fix the problem and what caused it?

```
1 - warning: htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument in /home1/XXX/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 856.

2 - user warning: in /home1/XXX/public_html/includes/cache.inc on line 108.
```

Comment: version of drupal? any upgrades that you have recently made?

Comment: neither of these errors are very specific and could be caused by any number of issues. you need to dig deeper into your error log to figure out where they are coming from or just suppress the error warning. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460440/how-to-fix-user-warning-cache-inc-on-line-109-from-a-drupal-site

Comment: Using Drupal 6.22.  No upgrades, thanks for the tip on only showing the error message in the log.